# Notice: Undefined index: validarUsuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax0.1\views\modulos\ajax.php on line 17

Tags: php, ajax

este es la clase ajax  donde la variable  validarUsuario  se manda de validarRegistro.js
.................................................................................

```
<?php  


require_once("../../controllers/controller.php");
    require_once("../../models/crud.php");
class Ajax{

    public $validarUsuario;

    public function validarUsuarioAjax(){
        # code...
        $datos = $this-> validarUsuario;
        #$respuesta= MvcController::validarUsuarioController();
        echo $datos;
    }
}   $a= new Ajax();
    $a-> validarUsuario = $_POST["validarUsuario"];
    $a-> validarUsuarioAjax();
```

js

validarRegistro.js este el javascript que lo envia a la clase ajax

```
$("#usuarioRegistro").change(function(){

    var usuario =$("#usuarioRegistro").val();   var datos= new FormData();
    datos.append("validarUsuario",usuario);     $.ajax({

        url:"views/modulos/ajax.php",       method:"POST",      data: datos,
        cache:false,        contenType: false,      processData: false,
        success:function(respuesta){

            /*if (respuesta ==0 ){

                $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html('<p> este usaurio ya existe</p>');          }else{
                $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html("");            }*/             console.log(respuesta);         }

    });

 });
```

me esta generando un problemas con la variable publica y no puedo
 recibir el valo de  input mediante validarUsuario para enviarlo a la
 base de da

Comment: Creo que se te faltó en el js, el "dataType" viendo que pusiste "data: datos" referiendo a otra cosa, en js.

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo raro en tu js, simplemente puedes crear un objeto datos y no instanciar un formData

```
var datos = {
    validarUsuario : $("#usuarioRegistro").val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "views/modulos/ajax.php",       
    method: "POST",      
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'text',  
    success:function(respuesta){

        /*
        if (respuesta ==0 ){
            $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html('<p> este usaurio ya existe</p>');          
        }else{
            $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html("");            
        }
        */             
        console.log(respuesta);         
    }

});
```

clase Ajax.php

```
require_once("../../controllers/controller.php");
require_once("../../models/crud.php");
class Ajax{

    public $validarUsuario;

    public function validarUsuarioAjax(){
        # code...
        $datos = $this->validarUsuario;
        #$respuesta= MvcController::validarUsuarioController();
        return $datos;
    }
}   

$a = new Ajax();  
$a->validarUsuario = $_POST['validarUsuario'];  
echo $a->validarUsuarioAjax();
```

Comment: pero si  no le incluyo en formData() donde alameneco la varibale para enviarlo

Comment: el problema lo tengo en la clases ajax que no me define la variable validarUsuario

Comment: Tu clase esta ajax.php esta bien solo faltaria algunos cambios para poder retornar $validarUsuario, edito

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: validarUsuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax0.1\views\modulos\ajax.php on line 16

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax0.1\controllers\controller.php on line 192
1

Comment: me esta generando esto , es que estoy haciendo una pagina web  y esta parte del codigo  es para cuando se registre un usuario  el ajax me lo mande para confirmar  si el usuario ya existe en la base de datos